# Why is my array always giving a true answer?

Tags: c++, arrays

My code here says that all values are true even if they aren't in the array. What am I doing wrong? For instance, I could input Chicago, and it will say "City found." I have tried to change the order around and change the "if(foundIt) to if(foundIt = true). It will still do the same.

```
// MichiganCities.cpp - This program prints a message for invalid cities in Michigan.  
// Input:  Interactive
// Output:  Error message or nothing

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() 
    {
   // Declare variables
   string inCity;   // name of city to look up in array
   const int NUM_CITIES = 10;
   // Initialized array of cities
   string citiesInMichigan[] = {"Acme", "Albion", "Detroit", "Watervliet", "Coloma", "Saginaw",     "Richland", "Glenn", "Midland", "Brooklyn"}; 
   bool foundIt = false;  // Flag variable
   int x;         // Loop control variable

   // Get user input
   cout << "Enter name of city: ";
   cin >> inCity; 

   // Write your loop here  
  for(int i = 0; i < NUM_CITIES; i++){
            if (x = i)
        foundIt = true;
      }


  // Write your test statement here to see if there is 
  // a match.  Set the flag to true if city is found. 
    if (foundIt)
      cout << "City found." << endl;
    else cout << "Not a city in Michigan." << endl; 





   // Test to see if city was not found to determine if 
   // "Not a city in Michigan" message should be printed. 


   return 0;  

} // End of main()
```

Comment: Please reduce this to a [example]. That means starting a new project from scratch  and using the *minimum* amount of code to reproduce the error, or cutting away pieces of this project one-by-one until it no longer exhibits the behavior (and adding in the last thing you took out).

Comment: if (i = x) is always true. You mean to say if (i == x)

Comment: x is also uninitalized

Comment: @John To be fair, it's somewhat minimal already.

Comment: Observe that `if (x = i) {...}` is equivalent to `x = i; if (x) {...}` Likewise, you never reference `citiesInMichigan` after its initialization.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat When I link MRE, I do it for one of two reasons 1. I'm having a hard time reading and following the posted code or 2. I think the poster will learn something and probably be able to fix it themselves in the process. I guess it can come off as kind of paternalistic though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This loop

```
  for(int i = 0; i < NUM_CITIES; i++){
            if (x = i)
        foundIt = true;
      }
```

does not make sense. There is used an assignment in the if statement of the control variable i to the variable x.

```
if (x = i)
```

It seems you mean at least

```
  for(int i = 0; !foundIt && i < NUM_CITIES; i++){
            if ( inCity ==  citiesInMichigan[i] )
        foundIt = true;
      }
```

If you need the index of the found city then the loop can look like

```
size_t i = 0;

while ( i < NUM_CITIES && inCity !=  citiesInMichigan[i] ) i++;

if ( i != NUM_CITIES )
{
    // the city is found at position i
}
else
{
    // the sity is not found
}
```